# .net core 2.2 httpclient Factory not giving Full data as response

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.2, httpclientfactory

I am using .net core 2.2 for my flight listing application and i am using wego api for that. but while i am using the below code for getting flights from wego api i am not getting the complete response, but in postman i am getting full result set at one request.

```cs
public async Task<SearchResultMv> GetFlights(FlightParam flightParam, AuthResult auth)
{
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://srv.wego.com/metasearch/flights/searches/" + flightParam.SearchId + "/results?offset=0&locale=" + flightParam.locale + "&currencyCode=" + flightParam.currencyCode);
    request.Headers.Add("Bearer", auth.access_token);
    request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");

    var client = _httpClient.CreateClient();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", auth.access_token);

    var response = await client.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);

    SearchResultMv json = new SearchResultMv();

    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        json = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<SearchResultMv>().ConfigureAwait(false);
        return json;
    }
}
```

Some time I am not getting any result set by the above code. Wego api is not providing any pagination or filtration on this api. so Please help me to achieve this. Thanks for advance.

Comment: You should send an image of postman and image or link of wego api documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According the their documentation you need to poll their API to get the results gradually. You also need to increment the offset as the results are returned.

For example, if the first set of results gives you 100 results, the following request should have the offset value set as 100. `offset=100`.

Documentation:
https://developers.wego.com/affiliates/guides/flights

**Edit - Added sample solution**

Sample code that polls the API every second until reaching the desired number of results. This code hasn't been tested so you'll need to adjust it to your needs.

```cs
const int numberOfResultsToGet = 100;
var results = new List<SearchResultMv>();

while (results.Count < numberOfResultsToGet)
{
    var response = await GetFlights(flightParam, auth);
    results.AddRange(response.Results);

    // update offset
    flightParam.Offset += response.Results.Count;

    // sleep for 1 second before sending another request
    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
}
```

Change your request to use a dynamic `Offset` value. You can add the `Offset` property to the `FlightParam` class.

```cs
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(
    HttpMethod.Get, 
    $"https://srv.wego.com/metasearch/flights/searches/{flightParam.SearchId}/results?" +
    $"offset={flightParam.Offset}" +
    $"&locale={flightParam.locale}" +
    $"&currencyCode={flightParam.currencyCode}");
```

Comment: yes but most of the time for the first request i am not getting any result. :(

Comment: It's not guaranteed that you will have any results in the first request. It depends on how long the search results take to be generated after the search is initiated. That's why you need to handle the logic on your side. You could write some code to send a request every second until you get the number of results you want.

Comment: So how i can do the client side filtration as their mentioned in thier document.

Comment: I've added an example to my answer so you can have an idea.

Comment: Thank you so much and let me check this

Comment: do we can load the data asynchronously to the view ?

Comment: Yes, it's possible but it's out of the scope of this question. Please open a separate question and if my answer helped you please mark it as the accepted answer.